# How to add a surcharge based on the delivery of state?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Per http://docs.woothemes.com/document/add-a-surcharge-to-cart-and-checkout-uses-fees-api/

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $county     = array('ME');
    $percentage     = 0.01;

    if ( in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_state(), $state ) ) :
        $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $surcharge, true, 'standard' );
    endif;

}
```

How do I add more than one state? So if the person is in OH or FL - I'd like to add a rate for each state.

Comment: Once state is selected you reqire Ajax to update cart value as well, refer code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390333/on-country-change-ajax-update-checkout-for-shipping-in-woocommerce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write some new code for it...I'll do it for you this time:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $state = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_state();

    if ( $state == 'ME' ) {
        $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * 0.01;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $surcharge, true, 'standard' );
    } elseif ( $state == 'OH' ) {
        // Do something else
    } elseif ( in_array( $state, array('FL', 'CA') ) ) {
        // Even something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I failed to say it's a different rate for each state. This will become more complicated?

Comment: Is every state included? If so, you're probably better off using [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), and adding each of the states as `keys` of an array, and rates as their paired `values`.

Comment: I don't understand...You won't even need `elseif` in that case. Just one `if` statement

Comment: Even if I use every state (51) and each state has a different percentage?

Comment: Correct, one `if` statement. Don't write `51` of them, whatever you do. `array_key_exists` is the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','xa_custom_surcharge' );
function xa_custom_surcharge() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    $state      = array('MH');
    $surcharge  = 10;
    if ( in_array( WC()->customer->shipping_state, $state ) ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Additional Charge', $surcharge, true, '' );
    }
}
```

Try this simple snippet. Got from [here](http://www.xadapter.com/2016/05/31/woocommerce-add-an-additional-fee-based-on-state/)